# E-mail (php+html+inline css) lost some formating

Tags: php, css, email

I need to send e-mail notification with some list in my web-app and i've faced with strange problem. When [list sent is short everything goes well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rxwrl.png) and all formatting presented, but when list counts somewhere about 17-18 items [all formatting is broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VXJ8.png).

- I've used inline css rules.
- All lines are shorter than 70 symbols (php wordwrap($text, 70, "\r\n") is used)
- DOM is correct and every opened tag is closed
- All special character are removed(js replace(/[^a-zа-яё0-9()\s]/gi, ' ') is used)
- This happens despite using some html or just putting text separated with space
- At the same domain,server, etc another script sending [large table with more
  complicated formatting works well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W4jhd.png)

Here's the e-mail content:

```html
From () 2022-07-18 17:50:57 +0000
Received: from myt5-173186d592cd.qloud-c.yandex.net (myt5-173186d592cd.qloud-c.yandex.net [2a02:6b8:c12:1723:0:640:1731:86d5])
    by g3osc2prw3r22pij.myt.yp-c.yandex.net with LMTP id gBanqaR2b3-SCZ0KBY0
    for <mailbox@yandex.ru>; Mon, 18 Jul 2022 20:50:57 +0300
Received: from web-relay.nicmail.ru (web-relay.nicmail.ru [91.189.116.19])
    by myt5-173186d592cd.qloud-c.yandex.net (mxfront/Yandex) with ESMTP id znqnbd3WFP-oueeu90s;
    Mon, 18 Jul 2022 20:50:56 +0300
Return-Path: mailbox@server.ru
X-Yandex-Fwd: 1
Authentication-Results: myt5-173186d592cd.qloud-c.yandex.net; spf=pass (myt5-173186d592cd.qloud-c.yandex.net: domain of server.ru designates 91.189.116.19 as permitted sender, rule=[ip4:91.189.116.0/24]) smtp.mail=mailbox@server.ru
X-Yandex-Spam: 1
X-Yandex-Uid-Status: 1 1561449865
X-DKIM: Exim 4.94.2 on web-relay.nicmail.ru
Received: from [10.1.115.211] (port=52242 helo=server.ru)
    by web-relay.nicmail.ru with esmtps  (TLS1.2) tls TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
    (Exim 4.94.2)
    (envelope-from <mailbox@server.ru>)
    id 1oDUtU-0005Kq-7k
    for mailbox@yandex.ru; Mon, 18 Jul 2022 20:50:56 +0300
Received: from admin by server.ru with local (Exim 4.94.2)
    (envelope-from <mailbox@server.ru>)
    id 1oDUtU-000Gc7-0a
    for mailbox@yandex.ru; Mon, 18 Jul 2022 20:50:56 +0300
To: Денис Петров — УК <mailbox@yandex.ru>
Subject: Заказ на продукты и расходные материалы
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
From: Моя пекарня <noreply@server.ru>
Message-Id: <E1oDUtU-000Gc7-0a@server.ru>
Date: Mon, 18 Jul 2022 20:50:56 +0300
X-KLMS-AntiSpam-Auth: dkim=none
X-MS-Exchange-Organization-SCL: -1
X-Yandex-Forward: a022c9e0e9760536b4202c7f58420048

<html style="background-image:
url(http://server.ru/.../images/satin.jpg);
padding: 0 0 20pt 0; margin: 0; width: 100%;"><body
style="background-image:
url(http://server.ru/.../images/0066-512x512.jpg);
border: 2px solid black; font-family: monospace; color: #555;  margin:
10pt auto 80pt auto; padding: 20pt 5pt 20pt 5pt; max-width: 500px;
width: 70%; box-shadow: 4px 4px 8px 0px rgba(34, 60, 60, 0.55);
-webkit-mask: linear-gradient(#000 0 0) center/100% calc(100% - 8px)
no-repeat, radial-gradient(circle 2px at 75% 0%,#0000 98%,#000) 50%
2px/8px 2px repeat-x, radial-gradient(circle closest-side at 25%
50%,#000 99%,#0000 101%) top/8px 4px repeat-x, radial-gradient(circle
2px at 75% 100%,#0000 98%,#000) 50% calc(100% - 2px)/8px 2px repeat-x,
radial-gradient(circle closest-side at 25% 50%,#000 99%,#0000 101%)
bottom/8px 4px repeat-x; mask: linear-gradient(#000 0 0) center/100%
calc(100% - 8px) no-repeat, radial-gradient(circle 2px at 75% 0%,#0000
98%,#000) 50% 2px/8px 2px repeat-x, radial-gradient(circle
closest-side at 25% 50%,#000 99%,#0000 101%) top/8px 4px
repeat-x,radial-gradient(circle 2px at 75% 100%,#0000 98%,#000) 50%
calc(100% - 2px)/8px 2px repeat-x, radial-gradient(circle closest-side
at 25% 50%,#000 99%,#0000 101%) bottom/8px 4px repeat-x;"><table
style="width: 100%; margin: 20pt 0pt 0pt 0pt;"><tr><td rowspan="2"
style="text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; width:40pt;
height:27pt;"><span style="display:inline-block; border-radius: 30pt;
padding: 0pt 10pt; background-color:#000000; color: white;
font-size:30pt; font-family: monospace;">И</span></td>
<td style="font-family:monospace; padding-left:20pt; color: #555;
font-weight: bolder;">Заказ на ингредиенты,
инвентарь</td></tr>
<tr><td style="font-family:monospace; padding-left:20pt; color: #555;
font-weight: bolder;">и расходные
материалы</td></tr></table>
<table style="width: 100%; margin: 20pt 0pt 0pt 0pt;"><tr><td
style="padding: 20pt 0pt 0pt 20pt; font-weight: bold; font-size:
150%;">«Таврия»</td></tr><tr><td style="padding: 0pt 0pt 0pt
40pt;
">Сосиски</td></tr><tr><td style="padding: 0pt 0pt 0pt
40pt;
">Ветчина</td></tr><tr><td style="padding: 20pt 0pt 0pt
20pt; font-weight: bold; font-size:
150%;">«Гранат»</td></tr><tr><td style="padding: 0pt 0pt 0pt
40pt;
">Смесь компотная</td></tr><tr><td style="padding:
0pt 0pt 0pt 40pt;
">Грецкий орех</td></tr><tr><td
style="padding: 0pt 0pt 0pt 40pt;
">Арахис</td></tr><tr><td
style="padding: 20pt 0pt 0pt 20pt; font-weight: bold; font-size:
150%;">«Ашан»</td></tr><tr><td style="padding: 0pt 0pt 0pt
40pt;
">Фарш мясной</td></tr><tr><td style="padding: 0pt 0pt
0pt 40pt;
">Тоник для лимонада</td></tr><tr><td
style="padding: 20pt 0pt 0pt 20pt; font-weight: bold; font-size:
150%;">ИП Архипов</td></tr><tr><td style="padding: 0pt 0pt
0pt 40pt;
">Филе горбуши</td></tr><tr><td style="padding:
0pt 0pt 0pt 40pt;
">Майонез</td></tr><tr><td style="padding:
0pt 0pt 0pt 40pt;
">Масло
подсолнечное</td></tr><tr><td style="padding: 0pt 0pt 0pt
40pt;
">Огурцы маринованные</td></tr><tr><td
style="padding: 0pt 0pt 0pt 40pt;
">Яйцо</td></tr><tr><td
style="padding: 0pt 0pt 0pt 40pt;
">Мука
пшеничная</td></tr><tr><td style="padding: 0pt 0pt 0pt
40pt;
">Мука ржаная</td></tr><tr><td style="padding: 0pt 0pt
0pt 40pt;
">Сахар песок</td></tr><tr><td style="padding: 0pt
0pt 0pt 40pt;
">Кетчуп</td></tr><tr><td style="padding: 0pt 0pt
0pt 40pt;
">Какао-порошок
(простой)</td></tr><tr><td style="padding: 0pt 0pt 0pt
40pt;
">Дрожжи</td></tr><tr><td style="padding: 20pt 0pt 0pt
20pt; font-weight: bold; font-size:
150%;">«Продсервис»</td></tr><tr><td style="padding: 0pt
0pt 0pt 40pt;
">Начинка маковая</td></tr><tr><td
style="padding: 0pt 0pt 0pt 40pt;
">Начинка
йогуртовая</td></tr><tr><td style="padding: 0pt 0pt 0pt
40pt;
">Начинка яблочная </td></tr><tr><td
style="padding: 0pt 0pt 0pt 40pt;
">Начинка
персиковая</td></tr></table><br><p style="font-family:
monospace; text-align: center; color: #1482b5;"></p><br><p
style="font-size:70%; text-align: center;">Кассир: Иван
Иванов</p></div></div>
```

Comment: You do have two closing `</div>`s with no corresponding opener, but that shouldn't be a problem.  Couldn't you do all those tables with a simple set of `<div>`s?  That's the "preferred" way today.

Comment: Web-interface shows well either short or long list, but i couldn't be sure what email-client my users will use, so it should work well everywhere. I'm using Spark if it's matter. 
Two closed divs are from debugging and i fix them, either divs or table don't solve the problem. Table's code copied from another script and it works well for 3 different types of notification.

Comment: Literally, you can't win.  You have to do due-diligence testing with the most popular email clients (Outlook, Thunderbird, Gmail, etc.), and if someone has one that is broken, you can't help it.

Comment: Thanks, Tim! I've realise it, but if i'm facing with a problem with my email client this isn't good, i've sent the broken mail to the developer may be it'll bring some light

Comment: Email renders are not very good.  I don't think you should expect complicated structures to work properly on all email clients.  Maybe attach a document to show the complete picture and give a summary in the email body.